# MySQL: Rank the total total amount with COUNT()

Tags: mysql, view, count, rank

Edit: I want to rank with COUNT()

I've made a View with every order a customer made. In the next step I wrote a query to calculate the total amount a customer purchased.
Now I want to rank the customers, based on their total purchase.

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT u.m_name, SUM(u.num * u.price) AS total,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM v_sales AS x
WHERE x.m_id = u.m_id
AND (SELECT SUM(s1.num * s1.price) FROM v_sales AS s1 WHERE s1.m_id = x.m_id)
>
(SELECT SUM(s2.num * s2.price) FROM v_sales AS s2 WHERE s2.m_id = x.m_id)
) + 1 AS Rank
FROM v_sales AS u
GROUP BY u.m_id;
```

But the results are not the expected ones:

```
# m_name   total   Rank
川島智弘    2620    1
河田英毅    0       1
山田忠明    15420   1
永峰弘万    500     1
永山智広    380     1
```

I need the following output:

```
# m_name    total   Rank 
川島智弘     2620    2
河田英毅     0       5
山田忠明     15420   1
永峰弘万     500     3
永山智広     380     4
```

Has someone an idea what I did wrong? It would be also helpful if someone could explain why my query doesn't work.
Here is a [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=db1d39d4e44b908bea431023fdb6ad13)

Thank you

Comment: The query in your question does not match the fiddle.

Comment: Of course it does, it's the last query in the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `RANK` function in MariaDB 10.4.

```
SELECT m_name, SUM(num * price) AS total,
 RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(num * price) DESC)
FROM v_sales
GROUP BY m_id;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=ce083122916315e7a323114d5dfadcde)

No window function:

```
SELECT t1.m_name,MAX(t1.total),COUNT(t2.m_name)+1 as RANK
FROM
(SELECT m_name, SUM(num * price) AS total FROM
v_sales
GROUP BY m_id) t1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT m_name, SUM(num * price) AS total FROM
v_sales
GROUP BY m_id) t2
ON t1.total<t2.total
GROUP BY t1.m_name
ORDER BY 3
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=79cc3d55f14c385c459b8bd1af8e056a)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I really appreciate it. But I am aware that I can use RANK. However we have been told to use COUNT instead. Did you have any idea? I am sitting there since hours.

Comment: See my answer added. It ’s a simple method. Maybe there is better method.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed. You really helped me out there!

Comment: Sorry. I forget to consider the case of the same value. Fix the query of no window function.